# png watermark in perl imagemagick, making png transparent

Tags: perl, imagemagick, png, opacity, watermark

Need help with perl imagemagick!

I am trying to put a png watermark on jpg image,

```
$image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Read('image_filename');

$logo = Image::Magick->new;
$logo->Read('watermark_filename');

$logo->Transparent(color=>'#FFFFFF');
$image->Composite(image=>$logo, gravity=>'southeast', geometry=>'-10-10'); 
$image->Write('final_filename');
```

Everything is ok, but I need my watermark is be transparent, when I am trying opacity=>'50%' it works, but the watermark png starts look like s...t:))

Comment: If you are reading the watermark from a file anyway, why not store the watermark file as an already transparent image?  It might eliminate the problem.  And the less you have to do programmatically the better.

Comment: Of course it will eliminate the problem, but I need to know the right solution!:) How to change an opacity of the transparent png correctly, by perl imagemagick??

Comment: Fair enough.  Just trying to think of a quick fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating the watermark by hand using GIMP or perlgrammaticly via GD?